# navigator.onLine returns false sometimes

Tags: web, web-applications, microsoft-edge, offline-mode

The property `navigator.onLine` returns `false` sometimes in MS Edge for some of our customers. Restarting the browser does not help. Only a different browser or the incognito tab works. Any idea what this could be?

We tried playing around with the offline mode etc., but were not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine), it says "*In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline*". So the customers may be in an offline situation. Besides, do they use any extensions in Edge? If incognito mode works, the issue might be caused by extensions. You can ask the customers to turn off all Edge extensions and tests again.